# Yellow precipitate in the presence of ammonium molybdate?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

We had analytical chemistry experiments to determine acidic radicals from a mixture of two salts. After the chloroform-chlorine water test for distinction between halides $(\ce{salt\ solution + H2SO4 + CHCl3 + Cl2_{(aq)}})$ when I emptied the test-tube in the sink, all of it suddenly turned yellow.

What reaction could have occurred to cause this?
The sink mostly contained diluted $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$ along with small quantities of $\ce{AgNO3, BaCl2, NH4OH}$, lead acetate and ammonium molybdate.

All of these would mostly be in small quantities since I had rinsed the sink with water before emptying the test-tube.

Comment: Off-topic, but important: why do you poor chemicals like these in the sink and not in the appropriate chemical waste container?!

Comment: We don't have an "appropriate chemical waste container". Though I hope all the sink outlets are connected to a separate tank.

Comment: @Michiel Safety and environmental concern is never off-topic.

Comment: @Martin That's why I still mentioned it, but with the 'disclaimer'

Answer (score 2):

> [...] diluted $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$ [...] $\ce{NH4OH}$ [...] and ammonium molybdate.

The yellow precipitate indicates that **phosphate** was present too. Under these conditions a yellow ammonium molybdatophosphate is formed:

$\ce{H2PO4^- + 22 H+ + 12 MoO4^2- +3 NH4+ -> \underset{yellow}{(NH4)3[P(Mo3O10)4]} +12H2O}$

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{PbMoO4}$ has solubility 0.00001161 g/ 100 g and is yellow. I believe, that with diluting acidity of the solution fell down, leading to significant deprotonation of $\ce{H2MoO4}$ and subsequent sedimentation of $\ce{PbMoO4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Wulfenite is a lead molybdate mineral with the formula PbMoO4. It can be most often found as thin tabular crystals with a bright orange-red to yellow-orange color, sometimes brown, although the color can be highly variable. In its yellow form it is sometimes called "yellow lead ore".

Comment: Permeakra already wrote about that, years ago...